# Why is there no output being returned from my check_esx_cim plugin?

Tags: monitoring, vmware-esxi

I've got several ESXi hosts running v5.0.0-469512 .  I'm monitoring these hosts using Icinga.  Recently I had to re-install one of these ESXi hosts and after re-installing I can't get all of my monitoring metrics.

I monitor using the check_esx_cim script which is a compiled python script for Nagios.  I've made sure that UserVars.CIMEnabled=1 is configured appropriately.  vSphere reports that the Secure CIM Server is running on port 5989 .  I can telnet to that port successfully from my monitoring host, so I don't believe there is any vCenter firewalling issues.

I even get monitoring data back for CIM_PhysicalMemory and CIM_Processor metrics.  But I get a "No output returned from plugin" message for CIM_Battery, CIM_Fan, and CIM_PowerSupply.  The same is true of the check_esx_temp.pyc script.

The documentation I found here is not very helpful in this case: http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/Monitor-ESX-hosts-in-Nagios-with-CIM-and-SSH/details

I've compared the working ESXi hosts with the re-installed ESXi host and everything seems to be similar.  I've restarted the Secure CIM Server in an attempt to resolve the issue.  I don't think NRPE is running on any of the ESXi hosts.  What other troubleshooting steps can I perform?  What other configuration steps have I neglected?